# Proving a relation between Ordinal Exponentiation and its corresponding set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> (Characterization of Ordinal Exponentiation) Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be ordinals. For f:$\alpha \rightarrow \beta$, let s(f)={$\epsilon < \alpha|f(\epsilon) \not= 0$}. Let S($\alpha, \beta)$={$f|f:\alpha \rightarrow \beta \land s(f)$: finite}.
>
> Define $<_S$ on S($\alpha, \beta)$ as follows: f$<_S$g if and only if there is $\epsilon_0<\alpha$ such that f($\epsilon_0)<g(\epsilon_0$) and f($\epsilon$)=g($\epsilon$) for all $\epsilon$ > $\epsilon_0$.
>
> Show that (S($\alpha, \beta)$, $<_S$) is isomorphic to ($\beta^\alpha$, <).

This is also a question that is listed in "Introduction to Set Theory" by Hrbacek and Jech on page 123. And here is my trial: First, I had to check if $<_S$ is well-ordered. I just checked the linearity and passed the well-ordering part, though. Then I tried to find a bijective function that preserves the order, which I couldn't.

To visualize easily, if *S* and $\beta$ has greatest element, then the greatest element in *S* would have the form (0, 0, 0, $\cdots$, $\gamma$, $\gamma$, $\gamma$) something like this(only finitely many $\gamma$s) where $\gamma^+ =\beta$. But I couldn't think of a suitable mapping of this element into element of $\beta^\alpha$.

Actually, I have no idea why the given conditions allow only finitely many elements of *f* to have its value other than 0. I just got stuck. Any hint is also appreciated!

Comment: How did you define $\alpha^\beta$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In my book, it seems the exponentiation is defined recursively: $\alpha^0=1$, $\alpha^{\beta+1}$=$\alpha^{\beta}*\alpha$, $\alpha^{\beta}$=sup{$\alpha^\gamma | \gamma < \beta$} for limit ordinal case.

Comment: So you have a definition for ordinal exponentiation already, and it uses transfinite recursion. So perhaps you should use transfinite induction on $\beta$ to show that the two are isomorphic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe you mean $\alpha$ in my question since it is on the exponentiation side? I think your suggestion is correct! But I still don't know how to use the fact that we've collected only those functions that have only finitely many values other than 0.

Comment: Yes, in your question the induction is on $\alpha$. If you consider the definition that you wrote in the comments, the induction is on $\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

You can prove this by induction on $\alpha$. The limit case should be fairly easy, as well the case $\alpha=0$.

To do the successor case, recall that $\beta^{\alpha+1}=\beta^\alpha\cdot\beta$, try to find an isomorphism between $S(\alpha+1,\beta)$ and $\beta\times S(\alpha,\beta)$.

(The fact that only finitely many points is non-zero is essential for the proof that the relation is well-ordered. Consider what happens if we take all the functions from $\omega$ to itself instead.)

Comment: Wow, I was at the exact situation you've described: I was especially having a hard time at the successor case. I'll think about the isomorphism later.

Comment: Thanks. Everything became clear now. Well, frankly, except one: I think since every set of ordinals is well-ordered, there's still no reason to restrict to those functions with only finitely many values not equal to 0. May I ask you a little bit more on the reason of that restriction? I think I'm just a little bit confused.

Comment: You should try and repeat the proof in the case where the support is not finite. See how it breaks down.

Comment: Yor are quick like a wind! Well, in the successor case first I assumed (S(α,β), <) is isomorphic to ($β^α$, <). Then we have S(α,β)*β is isomorphic to $β^α*β$ where the ordering on the left side is the anti-lexicographic. Enough to show that S(α+1,β) is isomorphic to S(α,β)×β. So maybe at this right moment of the proof I need that restriction? I'll try!

Comment: I didn't mean that proof. I meant the proof that the order is linear and well-founded.

Comment: Oh... Now I understood. Thanks indeed for your comments: those were really helpful.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.